# In Git, how can I reorder (changes from) pushed commits?

Tags: git, github

I have a repository with a single (`master`) branch:

```
a > b > e > f > g > c > d
```

It turns out that I need the changes in `c` and `d` (two commits toward the end of the history so far) to occur earlier, so that I’d have:

```
a > b > c > d > e > f > g
```

*Everything’s been pushed.* I understand I’m not supposed to rebase pushed commits, so what can I do?

Comment: If you are not allowed to change history, then there is absolutely nothing you can do.

Comment: Otherwise if you are willing to change history starting at `b`, then use `git rebase -i <b's hash>` and follow the prompts

Comment: You *can* change history, as long as you understand the (often severe) consequences.  If anyone else has done work on the original history, the change will make you very unpopular with them.

Comment: @NayukiMinase your `git rebase -i` comment should be an answer, really; after all, "not supposed to rebased push commits" is not a rule set in stone... Depending on the context of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that doesn't change history:

1. Use `git revert` to remove each commit from the branch.
2. Use `git cherry-pick` to reapply the commits in the order which you want.

Push these changes. This lets you change the order of the commits without changing the history.

Comment: Interesting, but does this actually have practical uses, or is it just for the narrative?

Comment: It has the practical use of reordering your commits without changing the history. Changing the order will have a practical use if you want to create a branch of one of the reordered commits.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot reorder pushed commits without `git push -f`. If this repository is shared between you and other guys, then you shouldn't do anything. If this is your own repo or it's on your own branch, use `git rebase -i <hash of a>`, then reorder the commits as you want, then `git push -f`.